# How to import com.google.zxing to Eclipse Web Project?

Tags: jsp, zxing, qr-code

[image]I want to make QR image and display it in JSP. I want to import com.google.zxing package. How fix all these import issues? Which all .jar files should I add to my eclipse Dynamic web project?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the zip file from Github and copied it to WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\